# Print first two elements of a String without null-check and try-catch

Tags: java

I got a question that how you can print first two elements of  String without making null check and using try-catch statements in case even if String is null.

String is not always null, it could be null so this case has to be handled without using null pointer check and try-catch statements.

This question was asked in an interview so at first It could be weird but if it was asked there should be a valid answer.

Thanks.

Comment: How can you print first and second elements, when the string is null?

Comment: What is is "first and second elements of a string"

Comment: Why don't you want to check for `null`?

Comment: Just pretend it's not null and then surround any written code with try-catch?

Comment: Besides that you are not allowed to use tyr-catch statements.

Comment: As I said that this question is asked in an job interview, I know that it could be weird but if it is asked there has to be an answer? is not it?

Comment: you never mentioned anything about try.. catch earlier..

Comment: I have missed that point, that is why EDIT button exist. So I have updated my question. So thanks for answer and you can remove it.

Comment: Updated question. It could be more clear now.

Comment: of course the EDIT button has button has server your purpose.. but the next time you downvote an answer be sure you have asked a right question, if you think the answer is wrong because of your question, then update your question and leave a comment in the answer about your update instead of downvoting it..

Comment: @Black Panther The reason why I am downvoting your answer is that I want to force you to remove the answer which makes my question to be removed. Otherwise I can not remove it. As you said it was my fault. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I have clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that `null` is replaced by the string `"null"` in String concatenation:

```
void foo(String s) {
   String s2 = "" + s; // Handle the case where s is null.
   System.out.println((s2 + " ").substring(0,1));  // Print space if string is shorter than 1 chars
   System.out.println((s2 + "  ").substring(1,2)); // Print space if string is shorter than 2 chars
}
```

Comment: Thanks,that is it. Up voted your answer. But how I can handle these downvoted? Do you believe that it deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: @mmc18 Things happen sometimes when a question gets edited. Don't worry about the downvoted answer, this is how stackoverflow works. If the person submitting the answer wants to, he can delete it.